# Root nginx to a folder inside a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

In our nginx configuration we've traditionally set the root to the public folder of our app and then set the location for the assets so that it would load up static files correctly:

```
server {

  ...

  root /home/app/public;

  location ~ ^/(assets) {
    expires max;
    gzip_static on;
  }

  ...

}
```

We've now moved this server to run a Docker container instead. Which means that public folder no longer exists on the server itself but inside the container. This means that any requests to our assets are being rooted to the wrong location and now respond with a 404.

In order to fix this, we've had to remove this `location` statement and instead rely on the application itself to serve static files (in this particular example via Rails' `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`. This is far from ideal as it now means the app itself is handling static files instead of nginx.

One option we've thought about was to mount the public directory...

```
docker run --name app -v /home/app/public:/var/app/public
```

But this brings its own issues such as now having files on both the server and the container and having to do a clean up task when we want to expire assets that exist on the server that no longer exist in a new container (especially if fingerprinted), etc...

**Is there a proper way to point nginx at the public folder inside a running container? Or is a mounted volume the only option?**

Comment: What's wrong with letting the application serve its own static files?  Your other option is to create a derived image `FROM nginx` that also `COPY`s the static files in.  I'd avoid any option based on mounting files into the container (you are likely to find a workaround involving shared named volumes, but this will ignore updates to the application, and it won't work in non-Docker container environments).